# Can I connect two Android devices directly using USB?

Tags: android, connection, usb

I need to write a program that will alow an Android device (running version 2.2) to send data (a simple String) to another device (also running version 2.2) via a USB connection.  Are there any libraries to do that?

Comment: Why should you use an USB connection? Every device is equiped with Bluetooth and can go over a larger distance than a simple USB cable?Here you can find information about bluetooth on android development: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

Comment: thinks for the answer, actually i need usb connection so i can save the device power.

Comment: I think the USB connection will also use some power. Maybe indeed not that much as bluetooth.
And i think the answer of @Jacek is the best then at this moment about the USB host mode.

Comment: I think its not possible to connect two devices with USB in android because its need adb port forwarding.. You can connect android device with system.

Answer (score 1):

I believe those devices would have to support USB host mode in hardware.  And then one of them would need to be out in storage media mode, then you'd use standard filesystem access functions.  But the hardware side needs to be dealt with first.  I would check out special USB host cables to see what can be done.  Not all Android devices can be put into USB host mode.

Comment: unfortunately android 2.2 does not support host mode, is there a way to work around this issue?